# How to Keep Formatting When You "Equal" a Cell in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google docs I like to often keep two cells in sync by using the equal sign, such as =A2 for example. The problem is that when I do this, the formatting of the cell is not carried over, and sometimes the formatting is important (text color for example). How can I keep 2 cells in sync including the formatting and not just the data?

Comment: Keeping the formatting of the cell using `= sign` is impossible, I suggest you can use macros, if you want to keep a specific format of the cell/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a formula of `=A1` is put to a cell, you want to sync not only the cell value but also the cell format.

In your situation, I think that it is required to use Google Apps Script. This has already been mentioned in Twilight's comment. So, in this answer, I would like to introduce a simple sample script for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, set your sheet name and save the script. By this, this script is run with the declared sheet.

And, [please install OnChange trigger to `onChange` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when the source cell format is changed, the script can be automatically run.

```js
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

function copyFormat_(src, dst) {
  src.copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
}

// This function is automatically run when a cell format is changed.
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType != "FORMAT") return;
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
  const src = sheet.getActiveRange();
  const ranges = sheet.createTextFinder(`=${src.getA1Notation()}`).matchFormulaText(true).matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false).findAll();
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  ranges.forEach(dst => copyFormat_(src, dst));
}

// This function is automatically run when a formula like "=A1" is put to a cell.
function onEdit(e) {
  const { source } = e;
  const range = source.getActiveRange();
  const sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  const formula = range.getFormula();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || !formula) return;
  const r = formula.replace("=", "").trim();
  const src = sheet.getRange(r);
  copyFormat_(src, range);
}
```

- In this script, when the cell is edited, `onEdit` is run and checks the formula, and when the formula is like `=A1`, the cell format of the source cell is copied to the active cell. And, when the cell format is changed, `onChange` is run. And, search the formulas directly using the cell, and the cell format is copied.

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This script is automatically run when the cell is edited and the cell format is changed. When you directly run `onEdit` and `onChange`, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.
- This is a simple sample script for explaining the method for achieving your goal. So, when you use this in your actual situation, please modify this script.
- In this case, when the source cell value is a rich text value, unfortunately, the format of the rich text cannot be synced, because of the current specification. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)