# onEdit and onChange for multiple sheets

Tags: onchange

I have a Google Sheet containing three sheets/tabs inside (COMMIT, TEAM, PLAYER). PLAYER is the main tab I use, and I want the data inside COMMIT and TEAM to mirror what is inside PLAYER. I have no issue getting the data to mirror, however, sometimes I change the formatting of words in PLAYER, but they're not copied over to the COMMIT or TEAM sheets, only the data.

Then I came across this tutorial:

[How to Keep Formatting When You "Equal" a Cell in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893588/how-to-keep-formatting-when-you-equal-a-cell-in-google-docs/75894239#75894239?newreg=5e6e749e6164491f9280cb9cb54475db)

It works great, however, it only works inside one sheet/tab and not between sheets/tabs. Is there any way to make it work over multiple sheets/tabs (ie. I bold and change the color of data in PLAYER, and that formatting is copied over to COMMIT and TEAM as well).

Thanks in advance!